# Copy or view numpy subarray using boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array, i.e.;

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
     [11,12,13],
     [21,22,23],
     [31,32,33],
     [41,42,43],         
     ])
```

I need to both create a new sub-array or modify the selected elements in place based on two masking vectors for the desired rows and columns;

```
rows = [False, False, True, True]
cols = [True, True, False]
```

Such that

```
print subArray

# [[31 32]
#  [41 42]]
```

Comment: Note that `copy` and `view` (as in the title) are very different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure that your `rows` and `cols` are actually boolean `ndarrays`, then use them to index your data

```
rows = np.array([False, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
cols = np.array([True, True, False], dtype=bool)
data[rows][:,cols]
```

*Explanation*
If you use a *list* of booleans instead of an *`ndarray`*, numpy will convert the `False/True` as `0/1`, and interpret that as indices of the rows/cols you want. When using a bool `ndarray`, you're actually using some specific NumPy mechanisms.

Comment: Great, thats clear now thanks. Just not as straight-forward as Matlab for same result. I have a [follow up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12437264/789215) - how do I do this in-place, without creating a new array?