# Modify numpy array section in-place using boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array, i.e.;

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
     [11,12,13],
     [21,22,23],
     [31,32,33],
     [41,42,43],         
     ])
```

I need modify in place a sub-array based on two masking vectors for the desired rows and columns;

```
rows = np.array([False, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
cols = np.array([True, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Such that i.e.;

```
print data

 #[[11,12,13],
 # [21,22,23],
 # [0,0,33],
 # [0,0,43]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436983/copy-or-view-numpy-subarray-using-boolean-indexing/) that you know how to access the rows/cols you want, just assigne the value you want to your subarray. It's a tad trickier, though:

```
mask = rows[:,None]*cols[None,:]
data[mask] = 0
```

The reason is that when we access the subarray as `data[rows][:,cols]` (as illustrated in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436983/copy-or-view-numpy-subarray-using-boolean-indexing), we're taking a view of a view, and some references to the original data get lost in the way.

Instead, here we construct a 2D boolean array by broadcasting your two 1D arrays `rows` and `cols` one with the other. Your `mask` array has now the shape `(len(rows),len(cols)`. We can use `mask` to directly access the original items of `data`, and we set them to a new value. Note that when you do `data[mask]`, you get a 1D array, which was not the answer you wanted in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436983/copy-or-view-numpy-subarray-using-boolean-indexing).

To construct the mask, we could have used the `&` operator instead of `*` (because we're dealing with boolean arrays), or the simpler [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function:

```
mask = np.outer(rows,cols)
```

*Edit: props to @Marcus Jones for the `np.outer` solution.*

Comment: Does the job, but how about "mask = np.outer(rows,cols)"?

Comment: Is there a way to get a view from boolean indexing? The above works just because numpy treats assignment differently. `data[mask]` is still not a view.

Comment: See a nice summary of views vs copies [here](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html).